# Как объединить миграции в laravel 5

Tags: laravel, миграция, объединение

Каким образом на проекте объединить миграции, допустим я создал миграцию для создания таблицы, потом я создал 4 миграции для его апдейта, как мне их объединить в одну миграцию? Желательно средствами самого фремворка чтобы данный в БД о миграциях сохранились или модифицировались

Comment: Антон, честно говоря пока так и непонятно, зачем тебе объединялка? Ты знаешь что такое миграция? Это описание операций с бд, которые выполнятся один раз в жизни. Зачем нужна миграция? Из документации следует, что для ситуаций, когда есть несколько разрабов, и всем нужно поддерживать бд в актуальном состоянии. Ты создаешь миграцию и проверяешь как она прошла. После ее применения в своей бд, она применяется другими разрабами в их базах. Если тебе нужно сделать еще одно действие в бд на следующий день, то тебе нужно писать НОВУЮ миграцию (эта уже применилась, все - забудь о ней). В свете этого ещ

Comment: используйте комментарии для уточнения у автора подробностей.

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора уточнить вопрос, оставьте комментарий к вопросу. Вы можете оставлять любое количество комментариев под своим сообщением. Когда ваша [репутация](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [комментировать сообщения любого пользователя](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/47953)

Comment: Не следует писать несколько ответов, просто обновите/дополните Ваш первый ответ.

Comment: Ну ок попробую по другому объяснить мне нужна всю эту тучу файлов удалить и по существующей базе сделать новые скрипты миграций, нужно например для переноса на новый сервер базы данных и чтобы не путаться в этой куче файлов при внесении изменений, а то сидишь и ищешь где этот файл в котором надо написать апдейт существующей таблицы. Например я сделал случайно миграции с одним и тем же действием артизан начинает ругаться что я уже это сделал в этой миграции, если я ее прибью то артизан начинает ругаться что есть запись о миграции, а самой миграции нет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Что будет, если редактировать миграции?**

1. *Жил-был проект.*
2. Я добавил возможность писать статьи на сайте. Добавил миграцию для создания таблицы.
3. Кто-то еще добавил подсчёт количества просмотров статьи. Добавил новую(!) миграцию.
4. Я в первой миграции изменил название таблицы с `posts` на `articles`.
5. *Кто-то расстроился.* Он ничего не получит после `php artisan migrate` и не сможет откатиться до пункта 1. Надо будет делать это либо руками, либо грохнуть изменения.
6. *Остальные тоже расстроились.* При попытке применить миграции на чистую БД - получите ошибку в пункте 3.

**tl;dr**

- Не редактировать
- Не удалять

Но если работаете сами и хотите <strike>приключений</strike> объединить или отредактировать миграции:

```
> php artisan migrate:reset
// объединяете или редактируете
> php artisan migrate
```

**Не убедил?**

Посмотрите в сторону генерации миграций на основе существующей структуры БД.
Например, на  https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator

Comment: во пасиб уже ближе по теме с генератором

Comment: в Laravel 5.5 добавили `migrate:fresh`, которая полностью всё дропает перед миграцией, но это избавляет только от необходимости всё чистить руками

Answer (score 2):

Что такое миграция? Это описание операций с бд, которые выполнятся один раз в жизни. Зачем нужна миграция? Из документации следует, что для ситуаций, когда есть несколько разрабов, и всем нужно поддерживать бд в актуальном состоянии. Ты создаешь миграцию и проверяешь как она прошла. После ее применения в своей бд, она применяется другими разрабами в их базах. Больше эта миграция использоваться не должна. Если тебе нужно сделать еще одно действие в бд на следующий день, то тебе нужно писать НОВУЮ миграцию (эта уже применилась, все - забудь о ней). Объединять все в одну миграцию - неправильно в корне с точки зрения самого смысла этого инструмента, т.к. миграция применяется однажды на всю жизнь. И если она прошла правильно, rollback может делаться ТОЛЬКО если ты хочешь 
а) откатить назад изменения в структуре бд (данные не восстановятся), либо 
б) убить бд и создать ее заново.

Comment: Так а как на боевом сервере то откат сделать? все же данные удалятся, че ни ужели нет инструмента которые по существующим файлам сделает один файл с всей структурой миграции, а старые прибъет

Comment: на боевом сервере тестовые миграции не делаются, насколько я знаю. Нужно тестировать локально, и когда убедились что все проходит как надо, тогда выкатывать на боевой. Действие отката само по себе автоматически не придумывается, там по умолчанию стоит "убить таблицу", но если нужен нестандартный откат, нужно писать в метод down процедуру отката.

Comment: так это понятно все, но проект то модернизируется в процессе, пока он модернизируется растет количество скриптов, вопрос как их объединить в одну, не ужели инструмента объединялки нету, единственный узкий момент во всем фреймворке

Comment: Никакого узкого места нет, вы не понимаете смысла миграций в принципе. Я исправил свой ответ, прочтите